# mobile view always view width as 980px. Can anyone help me detect what wrong?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, embed

I want to make a embed version for my site at url https://staging.immo-suedtirol.com/jobs/?iview=embed

It work well on desktop view. but on mobile view it seem not work. I use developer tool to check and see: site width always in 980px [This is what I see on developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYg2m.png). Content width always fixed to 980px for small screen view.

This really strange. This is first time I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add meta tag in the html header for screen width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag